# syntax error while updating database in mysql through vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

In the following code snippet I have tried to update the **student_info** table using mysql statements through an application interface in *vb.net*

```
Dim Connection As MySqlConnection
    Dim Command As MySqlCommand
    Connection = New MySqlConnection
    Connection.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=student;"

    Try
        Dim DataReader As MySqlDataReader
        Connection.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "UPDATE student.student_info set (Student_Name='" & SName.Text & "',Date_of_Birth='" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "',Department='" & ComboBoxDept.Text & "') where Roll_Number = '" & SRoll.Text & "';"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, Connection)
        DataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
        MessageBox.Show("Data is Updated !")
        DataReader.Close()
        Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Connection.Dispose()
    End Try
```

I received the following error :
     You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual the corresponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax to use near '(.......' at line 1

Here is the included image for error :

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlSEY.png)

Comment: Can you give us the definition for the student_info table? Maybe a filled in (with the values) query?

Comment: The student schema had one table named student_info with Roll_Number as the primary key ,Student_Name ,Date_of_Birth and Department as other attributes

Comment: Use parameters aswell. This will help in the long run. Right now you're open to SQL injection.

Comment: This code is just begging to be hacked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use brackets in `UPDATE` statemtment, multiple fields can be set by comma, e.g.:

```
Query = "UPDATE student.student_info set Student_Name='" & SName.Text & "', Date_of_Birth='" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "',Department='" & ComboBoxDept.Text & "' where Roll_Number = '" & SRoll.Text & "';"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The parenthesis were giving syntax error(s)